# Polymer - url rooting after deployment to subdirectory

Tags: polymer

Ive created a basic Polymer app from the starter kit (via Yeoman). I've today deployed it to the 'sandbox' on my domain and am getting a strange routing issue. The app is essentially a feed reader.

[View app here](http://purelywebdesign.co.uk/sandbox/f1feedreader/)

When I first visit the app I'm given a blank page whereas locally I'm taken straight to the feed. When clicking on 'News Feed' I'm then taken to the feed as expected.

I've added a route for the path of the domain structure as below but this did not fix it.

You can view the full code of the project [here](https://github.com/tonyedwardspz/f1-feed-reader).

**routing.html**

```
    page('/', function () {
      app.route = 'home';
    });

    page('http://purelywebdesign.co.uk/sandbox/f1feedreader/', function () {
      app.route = 'home';
    });
```

I've also tried:

```
    page('/sandbox/f1feedreader/', function () {
        app.route = 'home';
    });
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page.js allows you to configure the [base path](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/#pagebasepath):

```
page.base('/sandbox/f1feedreader/');
```

or just use `window.location` if you don't want to tie is to that specific deployment.

```
page.base(window.location.pathname);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the way the router page.js works. I assume you were testing with gulp serve (which creates a server and sets the web app base url of "/" to be localhost:3000/). The way you're currently setting your page.js routes is that it's looking exactly after the domain name and not at the "root" of the web directory.

In your case page.js is looking at everything *after* http://purelywebdesign.co.uk/ (meaning all your routes include should start from sandbox/f1feedreader instead of just /f1feedreader).

The documentation for page.js https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/ says that it uses regular expressions so you could also update the strings.